# How to load .so libraryes in my Python app that is running on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c, linux, ubuntu, .so

I have some shared object files (.so libs) that I need to load in my python project that will run on Ubuntu platform.

The goal is that I have some libraries that have already been converted into .so files and now I need to load them in my python project.

Can anyone share the detailed steps for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ctypes` for that, it's quite simple.

Say that you have a `my-library.so` with the following C function exported:

```
void say_hello(char *name) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

You would load the library and call the function from Python like this:

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
>>> mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./my-library.so')
>>> mylib.say_hello.argtypes = [c_char_p]
>>> mylib.say_hello(b"world")
Hello, world!
>>>
```

Note that the leading `./` is important, otherwise `LoadLibrary` will look in the default library path and not the current folder.

Fore more information refer to [the documentation for `ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).